# Change the Bold properties

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have this problem in this Code:

```
If RichTextBox1.Font.Bold = True Then
    RichTextBox1.Font.Bold = False
Else
   RichTextBox1.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

Here My problem:"RichTextBox1.Font.Bold = False" (This property is ReadOnly),
 I need some Help.

Comment: Create a new Font based on the current one, and set Bold accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RichTextBox1.Font.Bold = True Then
        RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End If
End Sub
```